# Python interpreter can't be set up for Eclipse to run Django

Tags: python, django, eclipse, homebrew

Inside Eclipse I would like to create a new Django project.

In the interpreter section I have pointed it to my virtualenv where Django is installed.

[image]

However in the screenshot below the "next" button does not appear to be clickable.

[image]

I am running in a mac with python installed via homebrew.

Comment: Just use aptana, its the same thing anyways.

Comment: from the interpreter selectbox, where Default is selected currently, can you choose the one you added recently?

Comment: @andrean yes I can select it.  But the button remains inactive. Strangely this is the environment on a friend's mac.  On my own mac its fine. It must be the way he had installed Python.  Not sure how I could solve that for him.

Comment: try to add django at forced builtins. I do this with Gtk, but have to be done for every project

Comment: @cox What exactly is forced builtins. Looking at it, it shows variables that I could add. How do I define them?

Comment: PyDev force introspection on this forced-builtins, and must be done for dinamicaly generated modules (like Gtk from gobject). Django made exhaustiv use of metaclases, so it may be on the same boat. Im not sure, I did not use django with Eclipse/Aptana(PyDev), but you won't break abything if you try